# Build Variable not Work in release in TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, release, release-management

I'm trying to work with release in TFS, I add a task a "Command Line"

to execute something like "python" in tool, I add a task a "Command Line",
 My file is in  C:\agent1_work\23\s\virtualenvtfs2\Scripts\python

Everything works fine. However when I've tried to replace the absolute path for something like

```
"%BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY%\$(virtualenvtfs)\Scripts\python"
```

or

`"${Build.SourcesDirectory}\$(virtualenvtfs)\Scripts\python"`

or even changing to

`"${System.DefaultWorkingDirectory}\$(virtualenvtfs)\Scripts\python"`

it repeatedly fails because it can't find the path specified.

Comment: did you try $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\virtualenvtfs2\Scripts\python

Comment: What's artifact you choose in release?

Comment: I do not use artifact because in the build i do not used

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in your question, you are trying to read variables from a build source directory **in a release pipeline** and that you have to do differently then you are trying.

In a release pipeline you have to add your builds as artifacts.

[image]

Then, your build will be in a directory that is ${System.DefaultWorkingDirectory}\build artifact name\your files

If are not publishing your artifacts in the build step, you can do it by adding the "[Publish build artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/artifacts?view=vsts)" build task in the build definition.

Comment: No, I don't publish in the build I want to publish in the release, also the task "Publish build Artifact" don't work in the release.   In my release I add the build as an artefact but how can I position on the C:\agent1_work\23\s ??

Comment: This is because the release expects to have a ready build, that was built using the build and not the release. So you could built it, publish the artifacts and then use the ready/successfull build and link it to the release as an artifact. You could use continuous deployment in the release to start it as soon as the build was successfullly completed.

Answer (score 0):

The build variables are not available in release, so you can’t use it. Regarding release variable, refer to this article: [Variables in Release Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch).

As Rodrigo said that, you can publish necessary files through Publish Build Artifacts task, then associate build to release, after that, the published files (build artifact) will be download to **System.DefaultWorkingDirectory** (e.g. C:\agent_work\r1\a)

Comment: the file that i want to publish will be generated in the release, in the build the file not exist yet, is there any method to publish the file , i test with the task "Windows machine copy file" but it not work, it gives me the error error 53

Comment: What's the requirement you need to publish the file during the release? Based on the original post, you want to execute the script file, where is this file? Is it on another machine? Provide the detail requirement here.